# How can I get anchor span text to show before the anchor in css or scss

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a vertical navigation menu with the normal ul, li, a layout, but with a span within the anchor holding text. The anchor is a white dot, increasing in size on hover and active. The text shows on hover and active.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="active"><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

The menu is on the right hand side of the screen. How can I get the text to show before the dot and aligned vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to make :after pseudo element.

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<ul style="list-style: none;">
  <li><a href="#" class="active circle"><span>Home</span></a></li>
</ul>

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  background-color:black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  content: '';
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7.5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7.5px;
  border-radius: 7.5px;
}
```

Here is code in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AndriiN/pen/MQBVPP)

Comment: As this is probably going to be the nearest to what I was asking, this will get the upvote, but I ended up using transparent backed tooltips.

Comment: thanks. hahaha, yeah, sometimes we are using that thing:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the bullet style of an unordered list, I recommend to disable the style and make a new one with the pseudo element before..

```css
ul>li{
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:15px;
  list-style:none;
  
}
ul>li:before{
   content:'\2022';
   margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a><span>1</span></a></li>
 <li><a><span>1</span></a></li>
 <li><a><span>1</span></a></li>
</ul>
```